# Primefaces @managedBean

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

i am working with 3.0 M3 . when i declare my managed beans in faces-config.xml, it works perfectly, but when i try the same codes with 
annotations @Managed bean @Request Scoped, it says  target UN-reachable.

i tried on 2.2 also, but it says same issue again.
I am using glass fish v3

```
@ManagedBean 
@SessionScoped
public class Profile implements Serializable{


    private String userId;
    private String password;
    private int code;

    public int getCode() {
        return code;
    }

    public void setCode(int code) {
        this.code = code;
    }

    private String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
```

Here is how i call them

```
<h:form>        
    <p:panel style="margin-top: 200px;margin-left: 300px;margin-right: 300px;" header="Welcome">
        <h:outputText value="Your Code ? "/>
        <h:inputText required="true" requiredMessage="Enter user id" value="#{Profile.userId}"/>
        <h:outputText  value="Password "/>
        <h:inputSecret required="true" requiredMessage="Enter password id" value="#Profile.password}"/>
        <h:commandButton action="#{Profile.varify}" value="Next"/>
    </p:panel>   
</h:form>
```

Answer (score 2):

Profile should be lowercase, and check the syntax on password line

Answer (score 2):

If you don't use the name attribute of the @ManagedBean annotation, you have to refer to the bean with the first letter converted to lower case.

From the [@ManagedBean javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17802_01/j2ee/javaee/javaserverfaces/2.0/docs/managed-bean-api/index.html):

> The value of the name() attribute is taken to be the
>   managed-bean-name. If the value of the name attribute is unspecified
>   or is the empty String, the managed-bean-name is derived from taking
>   the unqualified class name portion of the fully qualified class name
>   and **converting the first character to lower case**. For example, if the
>   ManagedBean annotation is on a class with the fully qualified class
>   name com.foo.Bean, and there is no name attribute on the annotation,
>   the managed-bean-name is taken to be bean. The fully qualified class
>   name of the class to which this annotation is attached is taken to be
>   the managed-bean-class.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using jsf2

you can do the following - give a name to the bean...

```
@ManagedBean(name="Profile")
@SessionScoped
public class Profile implements Serializable{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the import package of @SessionScoped, it must be import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;
and also give name to ManageBean @ManagedBean(name="Profile")